# Factorial calculator in c

Tags: c, factorial

I was practising some c programms for an upcoming check up at school and wanted to build a calculator where you can put in a number and it tells you what the factorial of that number is.
I programmed for a while and I am stuck at this point and I don't know what's wrong. Does somebody have any idea what is wrong?
"Fakultaet" means factorial.

```
#include<stdio.h>

int main(){
    
    int zahl;
    int i;
    int j;
    
    printf("Fakultaet Rechner\n===============\n");
    printf("Von welcher Zahl soll die Fakultaet berechnet werden: ");
    scanf("%d", &zahl);
    
    for(i=(zahl-1); i>0; i*1){
        j=zahl*i;
        i--;
    }
    printf("%s %d %s %d", "\nDie Fakultaet von", zahl, "ist", j);
    
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: What is `i*1` supposed to do?

Comment: Why do you use a `for` loop, but place the `i--;` at the end of the `for` loop body?

Comment: @progman don't you have to say what the programm should do with i at the third spot in a for loop? or could i just write i instead of i*1?

Comment: @Progman because it should take one away from i every time it multiplies or am i thinking wrong

Comment: You didn't check the return value of scanf to see if it succeeded. ```j``` is uninitialised.

Comment: @Luki But why have you placed it at the end of the `for` loop body and not placed it inside the third "argument" of the `for(...)` statement?

Comment: because i already wrote i=(zahl-1)

Comment: ```i * 1``` doesn't change the value of ```i``` at all. Any number multiplied by 1 remains the same.

Comment: @Luki Please see: [Why is “Can someone help me?” not an actual question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/284236).
Please see: [What Do You Mean “It Doesn't Work”?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/147616)

Comment: @Haris thats why i wrote i *1 so it stays the same

Comment: @Progman in case of a detailed describtion it outputs (for example if you want to know the factorial of 4) "Die Fakultaet von 4 ist 4."

Comment: For a given number ```5```,  ```i``` becomes ```4```, the condition is true, so we move forward, ```j``` is uninitialised and contains garbage. We can't proceed forward unless you initialise ```j```.

Comment: @Haris what should i write to initialise j?

Comment: @Haris Yes that's why I posted this question. Because it is incorrect.

Comment: You should initialise ```j``` with the number ``1```. That way, you would be able to store the result of the computation in it.

Comment: Unfortunately that doesn't solve the problem.

Comment: Now that your problem is solved, pick up good C book and read and understand it thoroughly. Learn how to use valgrind and turn all the compiler warnings up.

Comment: @Haris The problem is that my teacher wants the programm the same way he showed us and in a book it is likely to be different. For example how to set up a for loop etc. 
The problem with our teacher is, that we do very little at the lessons but everything is asked at check ups.

Answer (score 0):

I tried out your code and did not get a factorial value as the line of code where I believe you are trying to calculate it will always ultimately just multiply the user entry by a value of "1".

```
    j=zahl*i;
```

Also, even though the program does break out of the for loop, that is not a usual way to do it.  Probably, when compiled, you got a warning such as this.

```
    main.c|14|warning: statement with no effect [-Wunused-value]|
```

With that in mind, I tweaked your code such that it utilizes a for loop in a more usual and customary manner along with evaluating a factorial.

```
#include<stdio.h>

int main()
{

    int zahl;
    int i;
    int j = 1;

    printf("Fakultaet Rechner\n===============\n");
    printf("Von welcher Zahl soll die Fakultaet berechnet werden: ");
    scanf("%d", &zahl);

    for(i = 1; i <= zahl; i++)  /* More usual and customary way to set up and utilize a for loop */
    {
        j = j * i;              /* This will provide the factorial */
    }
    printf("Die Fakultaet von %d ist: %d\n", zahl, j);

    return 0;
}
```

In testing this out, the following was the output at the terminal.

```
@Dev:~/C_Programs/Console/Factorial/bin/Release$ ./Factorial 
Fakultaet Rechner
===============
Von welcher Zahl soll die Fakultaet berechnet werden: 6
Die Fakultaet von 6 ist: 720
```

Give that a try to see if it meets the spirit of your project.  Also, you might want to invest in a book or tutorial reference on C programming to get a feel for the usual way code such as for loops are used.

Comment: Thanks for showing me a functional code! But I didn't get a warning when compiling.

Comment: The job of the book should usually do my teacher but unfortunately we do nearly nothing at the lessons but everything is asked at a check up. :(